# Android implementing fragments with a viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager

I'm considering modifing my app using fragments with a viewpager, instead of activities.

So, as I understand the situation, I should be able to modify my app, that it just contains one main-activity which contains viewpager and to this viewpager I can and and remove Fragments as I like it, is that correct?

If I am correct has someone maybe a link with a short example implementation (main-class + methods for adding and removing fragments).
...
If I am not correct can someone give me a hint what the cleanest implementation for such a problem would be.

Already thanks for your time and support.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the example on the ViewPager documentation it shows the usage with Fragments:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Comment: I already took a look at this before... but it is not really answering my question, whether I can use one viewpager for the hole app so that I just need one main activity that is using the viewpager, to show any fragment to the user.